# Issue while trying to analyze Code Coverage Results with SAP Design Studio on top of HANA

Tags: hana

I am trying to analyze Code Coverage Results with SAP Design Studio on top of HANA by following the process which is given in the below link but I am getting the status as completed with warnings while executing and the warning message that I am getting is

> Calculated Measure Coverage is calculated after aggregation, but an additional calculation scenario has to be generated for this analytic view. This could lead to unexpected result. For details see OSS note 1993033.

I had created three calculation views as given in the below link but while creating third calculation view if I am taking `float("column3")/"column2")*100`, I am getting error.

Below is the screenshot for it

[image]

The link which I had referred for doing this is

https://blogs.sap.com/2014/02/18/how-to-analyze-code-coverage-results-with-sap-design-studio-on-top-of-hana/

Comment: Well, OSS  note 1993033 is the number of a SAP support document. SAP customers can access those on http://service.sap.com. Providing access to the contents of SAP notes to anyone without the service login is prohibited, so copying the information here is not allowed.

Comment: then how did they could get the raw data for the example provided in the above link and why i could not get the raw data by following the same steps that are provided in the link i had follwed all the steps but while creating third calculation view if i am taking float("column3")/"column2")*100 i am getting error and more over i could not see raw data at all

Comment: You might ask the blog authors directly on SAP Community Platform.